# Insert image on the top of side bar in stream lit app

Tags: python, streamlit

Is there a way to insert image on the top of side bar in Streamlit app? I used the code as follows but it shows the image below the menu in sidebar.

```py
st.sidebar.image("st.png", width=70)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put logo and title above/on top of page navigation in sidebar of streamlit multipage app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251012/put-logo-and-title-above-on-top-of-page-navigation-in-sidebar-of-streamlit-multi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed HTML code using `st.sidebar.markdown` and `unsafe_allow_html=True`.

It would give:

```py
import streamlit as st
import base64

with open("st.png", "rb") as f:
    data = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")

    st.sidebar.markdown(
        f"""
        <div style="display:table;margin-top:-20%;margin-left:20%;">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{data}" width="100" height="150">
        </div>
        """,
        unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )

    st.sidebar.header("Part 1")
    st.sidebar.markdown("Here is some text")
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks where should I modify the size of image? like the width of image?

Comment: You can using `"width="100" height="150"`. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help me on centering the image ? t doesn't locate on center

Comment: Try playing with `margin-left:20%;` and changing the value